# speed when downloading static files with servicestack.net

Tags: servicestack

I am testing out a pretty basic ServiceStack setup, where i at the moment want to host some static static files. I am hosting the static file by placing them directly in the servicestack root directory.

When i want to fetch the file i just issue a normal get request as in : http://somehost.net/somefile.bin 
When i issue this request, using chrome, on the computer which hosts servicestack i get a immediate download of the file. If i try to down the files from another computer on the LAN (1Gbit network) the download crawls at around 6Kb/sec.

Anyone else had speed issues when hosting files like this with servicestack?

P.S: This is NOT a network issue.

Comment: Why is it not a network issue? What are the benchmarks results for local and remote call settings? What results do you get from an ASP.NET website serving the same static file sans-ServiceStack?

Comment: If i use return new HttpResult(new FileInfo("somefile.bin"), true) it downloads at full speed.

Comment: and what is the speed difference?

Comment: 6Kb/sec to 1.6Mb/sec when using browsers. Just tried with wget - and there i see no problem. Hang on - seems that this is not a servicestack issue. I'll ping in with a comment when i figure out the root cause.